# How to generate training data for OCR

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, data

I am trying to build and optical character recognition system for recognizing license plate (Indonesian licence plat), unfortunately there is no training set available but I found the font, I try to generate the training data by convolve  the image of license plat letter with kernels (somethings like gaussian blur,box blur) using python, but it does not resemble real data, here is the font look like:
[image]

and I want to generate individual letter, that look like this:

[image: plat kendaraan]

Do you have any idea how to generate training data like above picture, ?
thank you

Comment: What about creating a dataset? What is your system used for? Can you get unlabeled data easily?

Comment: It is dificult to get dataset, even unlabeled data set, the dataset should be a croped image of car plate license letter, the system is used for reading license plat number

Comment: I used deep convolutional neural network for classifiying digits, stroke width transform for detecting the text and k-means clustering text segmentation

Answer (score 8):

That's a very good question. I am facing a similar issue with different data, but my research led me to [this](https://matthewearl.github.io/2016/05/06/cnn-anpr/) which should be pretty much what you are looking for.